# Keyword argument repeated in python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build restaurant list site using Flask.

This is a part of my application.py code.

```
@application.route("/list.html")
def list_restaurants():
    page = request.args.get("page", 0, type=int)
    limit = 4

    category = request.args.get("category", "all")
    price = request.args.get("price", "all")
    area = request.args.get("area", "all")
    
    start_idx = limit*page
    end_idx = limit*(page+1)
    

    if category=="all" and price=="all" and area=="all":
        data = DB.get_restaurants()
    else:
        if category != "all" and price=="all" and area=="all":
            data = DB.get_restaurants_bycategory(category)
        elif price != "all" and category=="all" and area=="all":
            data = DB.get_restaurants_byprice(price)
        elif area != "all" and category=="all" and price=="all":
            data = DB.get_restaurants_byarea(area)
        else:
            data = DB.get_restaurants()

    tot_count = len(data)
    

    if tot_count<=limit:
        data = dict(list(data.items())[:tot_count])
    else:
        data = dict(list(data.items())[start_idx:end_idx])
    
    data = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]['res_name'], reverse=False))
    #print(data)
    page_count=len(data)

    return render_template(
        "list.html",
        datas=data.items(),
        total=tot_count,
        limit=limit,
        page=page,
        page_count=math.ceil(tot_counet/4),
        category=category,
        price=price,
        area=area)
```

This is the python code calling the HTML page where the error is taking place.
The HTML page (list.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>search</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <style src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header" id="logo" onclick="location.href='list.html'">
        <img src="/static/YomoJomoLogo.png" width="150px" />
    </div>

    <div class="contents">
        <div class="searchbar">
            <form>
                <div class="searchbox">
                    <a style="color: black;">검색</a>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="search"
                        style="width: 80%; height: 30px;"
                        placeholder="Search by restaurant name or menu name."
                    />
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        name="search"
                        onclick="location.href='search3.html'"
                        name="search"
                        value="search"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="login">
                    <div></div>
                    <input
                        class="loginbutton"
                        type="button"
                        onclick="location.href='login.html'"
                        name="login"
                        value="login"
                    />
                    <input
                        class="regbutton"
                        type="button"
                        onclick="location.href='register_restaurant.html'"
                        name="register"
                        value="register"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <br /><br /><br />

        <nav>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    //alert("{{category}}");
                    $('#category option:contains("{{category}}")').prop('selected', true);
                });
            </script>

            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Category</a>
                        <ul id="category" name="category" onchange="location=this.value">
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, category='Korean', price='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >Korean</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, category='Italian', price='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >Italian</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, category='Chinese', price='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >Chinese</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, category='Japanese', price='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >Japanese</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, category='Cafeteria', price='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >Cafeteria</a
                                >
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a>Price</a>
                        <ul id="price" name="price" onchange="location=this.value">
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, price='below 5', category='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >below 5</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, price='5-10', category='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >below 10</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, price='10-15', category='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >below 15</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, price='15-20', category='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >below 20</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, price='above 20', category='all', area='all')}}"
                                    >above 20</a
                                >
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a>Area</a>
                        <ul id="area" name="area" onchange="location=this.value">
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, area='school', category='all', price='all')}}"
                                    >school</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, area='front', category='all', price='all')}}"
                                    >front</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, area='back', category='all', price='all')}}"
                                    >back</a
                                >
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a
                                    href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i, area='etc', category='all', price='all')}}"
                                    >etc</a
                                >
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li style="float: right;"><a href="search5.html">random</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        {% if total > 0 %}
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <br />restaurant list - {{total}}<br /><br />
        </p>
        {% for data in datas %}
        <div style="float: left; width: 25%;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <a href="/view_detail/{{data[1].res_name}}/">
                    <p style="color: black;">{{data[1].res_name}}</p>
                    <img src="/static/image/{{data[1].img_path}}" width="200" /></a
                ><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <!---pagenation-->
        <div class="page-wrap" style="clear: both;">
            <br /><br />
            <div class="page-nation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {% for i in range(page_count)%}
                        <a href="{{url_for('list_restaurants', page=i)}}" color="black">{{i+1}}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>

        {% else %}
        <p class="ranking">
            Search Result
        </p>
        <div style="margin: 20px;">
            <p style="text-align: center;">No result.<br /><br /></p>
            <div
                style="
                    float: left;
                    margin-left: 150px;
                    padding: 40px;
                    border-radius: 5%;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: #f3f3f3;
                "
            >
                Register a new restaurant<br /><br />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    onclick="location.href='register_restaurant.html'"
                    name="register"
                    style="height: 30px; background-color: #738b5f; border: none; color: white;"
                    value="register a new restaurant"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                style="
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: 150px;
                    padding: 40px;
                    border-radius: 5%;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: #f3f3f3;
                "
            >
                Random recommendation<br /><br />
                <input
                    type="button"
                    onclick="location.href='search5.html'"
                    name="register"
                    style="height: 30px; background-color: #738b5f; border: none; color: white;"
                    value="random recommendation"
                />
            </div>

            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/workspace/flask/application.py", line 108, in list_restaurants
area=area)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 138, in render_template
ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 883, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 127, in load
code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 636, in compile
return self._compile(source, filename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 601, in _compile
return compile(source, filename, "exec")
File "/workspace/flask/templates/list.html", line 57
    
    ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

It keeps pointing the same **line**, *not a specific part of the code.*

I tried adding blank lines on line 57, and it points the same line syntax error. The code was working well and suddenly it stopped. I have no idea how to deal with this 'keyword argument repeated' syntax error. Looking for some advices!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the correct up-to-date list.html template?

Comment: I was expecting to find a repeated argument in one of the `{{url_for(...)}}` calls.  But I didn't see one.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <input
                    type="button"
                    name="search"
                    onclick="location.href='search3.html'"
                    name="search"
                    value="search"
                />
```

You're using `name="..."` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I deleted one of the name="" but it still gives me 'SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated.'